# Creating an animated, partial blur of an AVPlayer video

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, avplayer, core-image

I have an AVPlayer playing a video, and I want to apply a sort of "gaussian gaussian" / "reverse iris" blur to it.

What I mean by that is that I have the center of the video have the highest amount of blur applied to it and as you move farther out from that center point the video is blurred less. Like this:

[image: Botticelli Venus Blurred]

I then want to be able to move that blur around (e.g. back and forth across the video) as the video plays.

Any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: There are quite a few ways of doing this but what is the best one will depend on the situation... Is video fixed as opposed to taking frames from the camera? Is the blur location fixed or movable in real time? What blur algorithm are you trying to implement and how precise must the blur be?

Comment: Video is fixed; 
Blur is animated but not necessarily in realtime, the animation can be precomputed/applied before viewing/always be the same; 
As specified above I'd want a "gaussian gaussian" blur where the intensity of the blur tapers off as you move away from its center. 
Any thoughts on where I could start with this?

Answer (score 0):

The gaussian blur is usually separated into two passes, vertical and horizontal due to a huge performance gain. If a part of the canvas is not blurred then this method can not be applied directly. So a straight forward method is to create a single pass blur shader to which you add a location of the focus and a size. Depending on the current position of the fragment you can then adjust how much blur to apply to that pixel. This is simply modifying a standard matrix progressively use less samples around the fragment and to sale down the effect of far pixels (adding the difference to the center pixel) when near the focus.

A bit smarter solution is to blend the blurred version of the image with the original version. This result may not be exactly the same but it is extremely close. There are many ways in doing this and if possible it would be best to blur the whole video and preserve the original. You would then use 2 textures and blend them together on every frame to get the desired effect. BUT if you are awesome you will generate a single video which will have both the original and blurred version in it (for instance original on top half and blurred on the bottom) which will gain performance and will remove any possible issues by seeking through 2 different videos.

So to blend the 2 together using focus you will have pretty much the same shader procedure but easier. Use a focus point in a fragment shader and a focus size. Then compute the distance between the current fragment and the focus point to get the scale of the blurred image that needs to be applied. With the scale you can use `mix` to effectively combine the two.

This procedure is especially good if the user can change the focus as no additional computations must be done. Still blurring the whole video might be quite time consuming.

Anything in between the two procedures can be done. For instance you may use a FBO with attached texture to create a blurred version of the sample in real time and then use `mix` with original and the FBO texture.